# Python | Removing XML node using index - Out of index

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, indexing

I have a list of indexs I want to remove from XML using python:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
xmldoc = minidom.parse(file)
parentNodeName = "Message"
for i in index_r:
    x = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName(parentNodeName)[i]
    x.parentNode.removeChild(x)
```

After removing 656, it throws error:
IndexError: list index out of range

Knowing that the list contains 1000 counts.
If indexing is not an option. I can remove it by tag value. But I'm not sure how it's done.

The xml file I have:

```
<listMessage>
<Message msgID="00002" severity="High">
    <msg>00002</msg>
</Message>
<Message msgID="00001" severity="NotApplicable"**>
<msg> NA</msg>
</Message>
</listMessage>
```

I want to remove the nodes with Severity Not Applicable.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as Xet
tree = Xet.parse(file_path)
root = tree.getroot()
sev_codes = [] #provided list of sev codes to be excluded
for i in sev_codes:
    for j in root.findall(".//*[@sev="+"'"+i+"']"):
        root.remove(j)
tree.write("C:/Users/Scheduler1.xml", encoding="utf-8")
```